# Automation of publishing in Drupal using Rules and Workflow

Tags: module, workflow, drupal-modules, rules, drupal-9

I am currently working on automating status changes in Drupal, my task is to use the Rules and Workflow modules to configure status changes after a certain period.

For better understanding, I'll give you an example: I need an Article to automatically switch from the Draft status to the Reviewed status after a certain period of time after the Article is created (for example, 24 hours).

The problem is that working with the Rules module in Drupal version 9 is much more difficult for me than in version 7, because the module itself is not fully developed.

**I tried:**

- to install additional modules that would improve the work of Rules, for example, Rules Extras. It eliminated many errors in the development process.
- I also tried to install special modules for postponement - Scheduler and its add-ons. This helped to postpone the publication date, but if the status does not imply publication (Under Review), it is useless.

Nevertheless, I'm sure it's possible, but the method is difficult and tricky. I would be grateful for any help!